# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs on boot after starting CUPS

Tags: boot, 14.04, startup, lightdm

As I was trying to install an alternative keyboard layout I ended up deleting my /usr/share/X11/xkb/* folders. I tried to reinstall them with `apt-get remove xkb-data && apt-get install xkb-data`. I also ran an `apt-get update` somewhere along the way.

My problem is, booting now, I hang at `Starting CUPS printing spooler/server`. If I `Alt + Ctrl + F3` I can login but I cannot run `startx` (which seems relevant) because I get `xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused`

If I run `echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/lightdm.override` booting takes me directly to the login shell but I still cannot run `startx`.

Comment: Just a note, using the remove command with apt-get will not delete the config files and user files (at least I think with xkb-data). You need to use purge instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be with lightdm after an upgrade.

I was able to get it working with the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session` (I'm not sure if this is needed, I ended up not using lightdm anyway)

`sudo apt-get install gdm` (Select gdm from the list)

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` (Select gdm from the list)

`reboot`

This solution ends up with GDM as the display manager for Ubuntu, but I like the look and it runs better on my machine.

Some links that may be useful:

[General "Computer boots to black screen" problem troubleshooting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078)

Comment: I had a similar problem (boot hanging after the CUPS line, but I could drop into a shel with ctrl+alt+f4) and my solution involved `sudo apt-get remove lightdm` and `sudo apt-get install lightdm`. Also one or two rounds of booting into recovery mode and choosing the `dpkg` option to fix broken packages (though not sure if that was the problem)